# Maya - How can I move multiple objects from a center point outwards

Tags: python, maya, mel

[image]

a=As you can see in the picture, I want to have 3 pieces of objects ( 3 Sector of a cylinder ) ( Maya 2017 ). And I want it to be moving them equally outward or in from/to the center point of them. I also don't want any scale in their size. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in a CG group ...

It solve with "Constraint Parent" tool. You must place an object (any thing) in the center of 3 targeted objects. Then use "constraint parent" to parent 3 objects to center object. hen when you Scale the center object, the other 3, just moving outward and don't scale.
I believe this is the simplest and a standard way to doing such a things.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple MEL script with abstract geometry that you can adapt for your purposes.

Remember, you need to move all the pivots to appropriate coordinates. In my case it's `0` `0` `0`.

For variable `$trans` you can assign a distance that the geometry travels along (in local axis).

```
polyPyramid -w 3 -ns 4 -sh 1 -sc 0 ;
setAttr "pPyramid1.rotateY" 45 ;
select -r pPyramid1 ;
move -r 0 1 0 pPyramid1.scalePivot pPyramid1.rotatePivot ;
move -r -os -wd 0 -1 0 ;

duplicate -rr ; 
rotate -r 0 0 90 ; 
for ( $i = 1; $i < 3; ++$i ) 
    duplicate -rr -st ; 

// This is a part of script for translating pyramids along their Y local axis

select pPyramid1 pPyramid2 pPyramid3 pPyramid4 ;
$trans = -5 ;
move -r -os -wd 0 $trans 0 ;
```

[image]
[image]